# how to get information from url into variable

Tags: php, url, reverse-geocoding

So i'm trying to get location usng reverse geocoding 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding
so my question is (since i'm very new to php) how to get the result from URL into parameter (the result will be json encoded data)

Comment: use json_decode to convert into php object/array *. then assign like $variable=whatever-json-decode-blah-blah

Comment: i'm not sure that u understanded my question. I need to get that json data from that url. How to do that?

Comment: use curl http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php or any

Answer (score 0):

you can use function ***file_get_contents*** to get Data from URL

```
    $API_KEY ="XXXXXXX";
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=".$API_KEY;
    $data = @file_get_contents($url);
    $jsondata = json_decode($data,true);
    if(is_array($jsondata) && $jsondata['status'] == "OK")
    {
         echo '<pre>'; print_r($jsondata);echo '</pre>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the data we use the PHP curl functions.

[php]

```
// jSON URL which should be requested
$json_url = ‘www.yourdomain.com';

$username = ‘your_username';  // authentication
$password = ‘your_password';  // authentication

// jSON String for request
$json_string = ‘[your json string here]';

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . “:” . $password,  // authentication
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(‘Content-type: application/json’) ,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_string
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

// Getting results
$result = curl_exec($ch); // Getting jSON result string
```

[/php]

The result will be a jSON string.

Normally you have to send a jSON string to the jSON URL and you will get a jSON string back. To encode your data, just use the php jSON functions.  Use json_encode to create a json string from your PHP array and use json_decode to transform the jSON string to PHP array.